# Form validation without submit button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I a have a simple form, which I need to validate. How can I validate it without button(submit)?

```html
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Info</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="myName" required/>
        </div>
       <div>
           <label for="pass">Password:</label>
           <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" ng-model="myPass" required/>
       </div>
       <div>
           <label for="email">Email:</label>
           <input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="myMail" required/>
       </div>
        <div>
            <label for="birth">Date of birth:</label>
            <input type="date" id="birth" name="birth" ng-model="date"/>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you need to validate? Pass? Name? Email? Maybe you need a pattern in the input.

Comment: You can validate on lostfocus event of last textbook if you dont want to use button

Comment: your question doesn't make sense.  in some of the deleted comments, you suggested that you are trying to submit the form without a submit button, but that's not what you asked for in the question body.  as to validation, you already have validation hooked up for `required` on these inputs, but you haven't described what it is you are expecting to happen.

Comment: I mean if all fields are completed and valid, form confirms automatically without click on `Submit` button. Something like after loosing focus in last field

Comment: You mean you want the form to submit itself after the last field is filled in?   That's not what validation means.  (It's also not a very good idea from a UI perspective: users don't expect forms to submit themselves without warning).

Answer (score 0):

By default, Angular form validation will trigger automatically whenever the data changes (whether from the model or based on direct user input), it's not tied to form submit.  You can modify which events trigger this using `ng-model-options`, as in

```
<input ng-model-options="{
    updateOn: 'default blur', 
    debounce: { default: 500, blur: 0 } 
}" ...>
```

If you need to create your own custom validator, add it to `ngModelController.$validators` or `$asyncValidators`, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="myName" validatename required/>
```

```
app.directive('validatename', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.validatename = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          return true;
        }

        if (viewValue === "Zuul") {
          return true; 
        }

        return false; // There is no Dana only Zuul
      };
    }
  };
});
```

I believe you can also trigger validation programmatically by calling `$validate()` but this is rarely necessary.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms